# I am struggling to implement an API call in Axios/Fetch that requires OAuth1.0 and need some guidance

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch, postman, oauth-1.0a

I am building a react web app that needs to pull data from the Gravity Forms API. Someone has set up the Consumer_Key and Secret_key for me and I have it working fine in Postman.

I have not used OAuth with an API call in Javascript before and am struggling to find a way to implement it. As I understand it, the call first needs to send my keys, then it recieves a 'nonce' and timestamp, then it needs to send the call again with all these things added and then I get my result.

I've poured through the Axios docs, as well as the Gravity Forms docs (https://docs.gravityforms.com/rest-api-v2-authentication/) and done plenty of Goggling but am so far drawing a blank. I've seen suggestions of using an interceptor with Axios but that answer was downvoted to 0 on here. Also I have come across some specific OAuth node libraries but I am not sure if a Node library is what I want for a front-end (React) call.

This is what I send in Postman:

[image: This is what I send in Postman:]

And this is the response I get:

[image: And this is the response I get:]

Looking through the Axios requests that Postman generates after a successful call I've noticed this pattern in the URL:

const apiString = `${API_URL}${API_FIELDS}&oauth_consumer_key=${CONSUMER_KEY}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&&oauth_timestamp=${oauthTimeStamp}&oauth_nonce=${oauthNonce}&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=${oauthSignature}`;

I already have the variables in capitals so I guess I need to find a way of generating the ones in camelCase and then building my URL?

Alternatively does anyone have an up to date guide of how to implement this API call using just Axios or Fetch?

Comment: Since you seem to be on the way to building your own implementation, you should really just start with the OAuth specs themselves instead of guessing what everything is

Comment: https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/